# Solving linear differential equation with Fourier transform

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to solve $$y''(x)+2y'(x)+y(x)=f(x)$$ for $y(x)$ with the Fourier transform. $f$ is from Schwartz space.

**EDIT:** I removed my old incorrect derivation and gave a correct answer below. - This equation can be solved easier using [integrating factors.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html) - Thanks to [Physicist137](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/169193/physicist137) for the help!

Comment: Why do you want to solve that differential equation with fourier transform? There are easier ways. In addition, the last integral you are stuck, can be solved easily using residue theorem.

Comment: I edited my answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got some time. Here is the correct full answer using the following definition of the Fourier-transform  $\mathcal{F}(y(x))$ for a function  $y(x)$ $$\mathcal{F}(y(x))(k):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}y(x)e^{-ikx} dx.$$

FT is linear so $$ \mathcal{F}(y''+2y'+y)=\mathcal{F}(f)$$
$$\Rightarrow\mathcal{F}(y'')+2\mathcal{F}(y')+\mathcal{F}(y)=\mathcal{F}(f).$$
With the property $\mathcal{F}(y')=ik\mathcal{F}(y)$ the equation turns into
$$(-k^2+2ik+1)\mathcal{F}(y)=-(k-i)^2\mathcal{F}(y)=\mathcal{F}(f).$$
To make things more compact let's define
$$\mathcal{F}(y)=\frac{-1}{(k-i)^2}\mathcal{F}(f)=:\mathcal{F}(h)\mathcal{F}(f),$$
assuming that $h(x)$ exists.
Using the convolution theorem, we obtain
 $$\mathcal{F}(y)=\mathcal{F}(h)\mathcal{F}(f)=\mathcal{F} (h* f).
$$
Using inverse FT we get 
$$y(x)=(h* f)(x)$$

Now, let's solve the integral 
$$h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathcal{F}(h(x))(k)e^{ikx} dk=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{-1}{(k-i)^2}e^{ikx} dk$$

Here we have to be careful what $x\in \mathbb{R}$  we put into that integral but more about that later. Solving this real integral using the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) is quite nice. In order to be able to do that, we need a complex function and a closed path on the complex plane.

Let's make another definition 
$$ \mathcal{F}(h(x))(\alpha):=\tilde{h}(\alpha), \quad \text{for}\quad \alpha\in \mathbb{K}. $$

For clarification: $\tilde{h}(k)$ is the function $\tilde{h}$ with a real input $k$ and $\tilde{h}(z)$ is the same function with a complex input $z$.

Now, $\tilde{h}(z)$ has a singularity of second order at $z=i$ and analytic everywhere else in $\mathbb{C}$. This is our complex function for the residue theorem. Let the closed path be $\gamma$, the upper half of a circle with radius $R$ and center located at the origin of the complex plane and the interval (-R,R). Let the orientation of $\gamma$ be positive, i.e. it goes from $-R$ to $R$ then from $R$ to $iR$ on a quater circle and from $iR$ to $-R$ on a quater circle. The circle part of $\gamma$ I will call $\gamma '$. $\gamma ' $ has the same oriention as $\gamma.$ When we let $R\rightarrow\infty,$ we get

\begin{equation}
\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\oint_{\gamma} \tilde{h}(z) e^{izx}dz=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int_{-R}^R \tilde{h}(k) e^{ikx}dk+\int_{\gamma '}\tilde{h}(z)e^{izx}dz\right).
\label{one}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Assuming that 
$$
\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-R}^R \tilde{h}(k) e^{ikx}dk=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \tilde{h}(k) e^{ikx}dk, \tag{*}\label{star}
$$
we just have to calculte the two complex integrals and set the result equal the real integral. - With the residue theorem we get that, for **any** $R>1$
$$
\oint_{\gamma} \tilde{h}(z) e^{izx}dz=\oint_{\gamma} \frac{-1}{(z-i)^2}  e^{izx}dz=2\pi i\cdot \mathrm{Res}\left(\tilde{h}(z) e^{izx},i\right)=
$$
$$
2\pi i \cdot\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{d}{dz}\left((z-i)^2 \frac{-1}{(z-i)^2}  e^{izx}\right)=2\pi i \cdot\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\left(-ixe^{izx} \right)=2\pi x e^{-x}.
$$
$R>1$ otherwise the singularity at $z=i$ would not be included and the value of the integral would be zero.

Let's now look at the second complex inegral
$$
\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\gamma '}\tilde{h}(z)e^{izx}dz.
$$
If we look at the absolute value as $R\rightarrow \infty$
$$
\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\left| \int_{\gamma '}\tilde{h}(z)e^{izx}dz\right|\leq\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{max}\left| \tilde{h}(z)e^{izx}\right|\pi R=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{max}\left| \frac{-1}{(z-i)^2}e^{iax}e^{-bx}\right|\pi R=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{max}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^4+...}}|e^{iax}|e^{-bx}\right)\pi R.
$$

The $...$ is non negative.
Now we understand why we had to be careful what x to put in! In this case we are in the upper half of the semi circle, i.e. $z=a+bi$ with $|z|=R$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R^+}.$ That means the limit is only zero if $x\geq 0.$

From \eqref{star} we get that \eqref{one} is 
$$
2\pi x e^{-x}=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \tilde{h}(k) e^{ikx}dk \quad \forall x\geq 0
$$
This means that $$
h(x)=\sqrt{2\pi} x e^{-x} \quad\forall x\geq 0
$$
To find out what h(x) is $\forall x<0$ we can give a very simliar argument. We integrate the lower half of the semi circle with the $(-R,R)$ real segment where $\gamma$ and $\gamma '$ have both negative orientation. Then we would get 
$$
h(x)=0 \quad \forall x\leq 0
$$

So finally this gives us 
$$
h(x)=\sqrt{2\pi} x e^{-x}\theta(x),
$$
where $\theta(x)$ is the [Heaviside step function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html) and
$$
y(x)=(h*f)(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(\alpha)h(x-\alpha) d\alpha=\int_{-\infty}^x f(\alpha)(x-\alpha)e^{\alpha -x}d\alpha.
$$

Thanks to Physicist137 for the hint!

Note: This is not the way I would have solved this equation. It is much easier to solve via the **method of integrating factor.** (sorry I can only post two links it seems..)

Comment: Very nice. Obs.: You can post multiple links using this format: [link description](link_here).

Answer (score 0):

Well... Apparently you have took the longer way in almost all steps. =(. Anyway.. the problem is the residue. You computed it wrong.

Notice:
$$
(z-i) = -i(iz+1) = -i(1+iz) \quad\implies\quad
(z-i)^2 = (1+iz)^2
$$

Therefore: $(z-i)^2 f(z) = e^{ixz}$. So, the residue is its derivative:
$$
Res\{f(z), i\} = \frac{d}{dz}\left[(z-i)^2 f(z)\right]_{z=i}
= \frac{d}{dz}\left[e^{ixz}\right]_{z=i}
= \left[ix e^{ixz}\right]_{z=i}
= ix e^{-x}
$$

As you can see we don't have the minus sign. Thus inverse fourier transform is actually $-\sqrt{2\pi}x e^{-x}$.

About the interval.. I don't quite know. It has definitly something to do about convergence of the fourier transform of the function $-\sqrt{2\pi}x e^{-x}$.

Comment: You forgot the sign  in $(z−i)^2=-(1+iz)^2$

Comment: @ty. Errr.... indeeeeed. This answer seems useless then.